# wxPython event queue stops processing events when wxMessageDialog is shown

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

Can anyone explain why the custom event handler stops being called when the message dialog is displayed?

```
import threading
import time
import wx
from wx.lib.newevent import NewEvent


CustomEvent, EVT_CUSTOM = NewEvent()


class EventProducer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, consumer):
        self.running = True
        self._consumer = consumer
        self._production_count = 0
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        
    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            data_string = f'Test Data:{self._production_count}'
            print(f'Producing Event: {data_string}')
            event = CustomEvent(data=data_string)
            wx.PostEvent(self._consumer, event)
            self._production_count += 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
            
            
class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.button_id = wx.NewIdRef()      
        self._button = wx.Button(self, id=self.button_id, label='Test Button')
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(selenter code heref._button, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        
        self.Bind(EVT_CUSTOM, self._handle_custom_event)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._handle_button_event, id=self.button_id)
        self._producer = EventProducer(self)
                
    def _handle_custom_event(self, event):
        print(f'\tConsuming Event: {event.data}')
        
    def _handle_button_event(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'Test Message', 'Test Message')
        dlg.ShowModal()

    def start_events(self):
        self._producer.start()


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, title='Test Frame')
        self._panel = TestPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self._panel, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        
        self._panel.start_events()
        
class App(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._frame = None
        
    def OnInit(self):
        self._frame = MainFrame()
        self._frame.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Then output from the program:

```
Producing Event: Test Data:0
    Consuming Event: Test Data:0
Producing Event: Test Data:1
    Consuming Event: Test Data:1
Producing Event: Test Data:2
    Consuming Event: Test Data:2
Producing Event: Test Data:3
    Consuming Event: Test Data:3
Producing Event: Test Data:4
    Consuming Event: Test Data:4
Producing Event: Test Data:5
    Consuming Event: Test Data:5
Producing Event: Test Data:6
    Consuming Event: Test Data:6
```

When the button is clicked and the message dialog is displayed, the event handle to the custom event stops getting called. It does get called when the mouse is moved over the main frame, as shown below. If the mouse is move away from the frame entirely the event handle stops being called altogether.

```
Producing Event: Test Data:7
Producing Event: Test Data:8
    Consuming Event: Test Data:7
    Consuming Event: Test Data:8
Producing Event: Test Data:9
Producing Event: Test Data:10
    Consuming Event: Test Data:9
    Consuming Event: Test Data:10
Producing Event: Test Data:11
Producing Event: Test Data:12
Producing Event: Test Data:13
Producing Event: Test Data:14
Producing Event: Test Data:15
Producing Event: Test Data:16
    Consuming Event: Test Data:11
    Consuming Event: Test Data:12
    Consuming Event: Test Data:13
    Consuming Event: Test Data:14
    Consuming Event: Test Data:15
    Consuming Event: Test Data:16
Producing Event: Test Data:17
Producing Event: Test Data:18
Producing Event: Test Data:19
Producing Event: Test Data:20
Producing Event: Test Data:21
Producing Event: Test Data:22
Producing Event: Test Data:23
    Consuming Event: Test Data:17
    Consuming Event: Test Data:18
    Consuming Event: Test Data:19
    Consuming Event: Test Data:20
    Consuming Event: Test Data:21
    Consuming Event: Test Data:22
    Consuming Event: Test Data:23
Producing Event: Test Data:24
    Consuming Event: Test Data:24
Producing Event: Test Data:25
    Consuming Event: Test Data:25
```

Comment: the dialog starts his own event queue.

Comment: Yes I believe so, the issue is that the dialogue can be open for extended periods of time before it will be checked. During this time the custom event will consume memory / go unserviced. I assume the message dialogs are not meant to be used this way. Or is there a there something I can do to the event queues to ensure the custom events are still processed ?

Comment: what do you mean by `consume memory/go unserviced`?  And if you want to still process the event you can write its handler in the dialog and it will be processed. You just need to send that event appropriately, in case the dialog is opened.

Comment: I haven't looked at it in detail but the clue might be in the `ShowModal`. Dialogs - They are all ‘modal’, grabbing the flow of control until the user dismisses the dialog, to make them easy to use within an application.